# Custom File structure for Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, filestructure

I have a client requirement that requires a custom file structure for symfony, where i have to keep source files in the following

```
/src/files/*.php (project files goes here)
/lib/symfony/vendor (all symfony related files goes here)
/resources/js/*.js
/resources/css/*.css
```

In the above structure, where should the app directory and its sub directories (app/cache, app/config, app/log etc.)be located? I see example of changing autoload.yml file. Where this file should be located for the above structure? I am not entirely clear about this.

Can someone give an example to configure for one of the above paths?.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Bharani

Comment: Sorry but I have to say this: this specifications seem to be for Symfony1, not Symfony2.

Comment: Do you know how to do it in Symfony 2 as I am using symfony 2.5 now.

Comment: Some clever symlinking could do the trick. To the unknowing it would appear the filesystem is the way you desire, however, the reality will be that it will be the symfony2 default.

Comment: Not really... mainly because I doubt anyone ever did it. This requirement by your client is just really outdated. it requires the structure of Symfony1 which isn't maintained anymore since 2012. If the client wants symfony1, he has to acknowledge the implications (security, longer development times, more expensive). To make it run with Symfony2 you would basically start with rewriting the autoloader. That also means that a simple `composer update` or install isn't possible anymore and I doubt it will be done quick. Next would be the web/app.php

Comment: @phpisuber01 Yeah. Please don't suggest to lie to clients or trick them.

Comment: I think client wants it and I have to implement it somehow. My confusion is where will I put that autoload.yml file? 

I also see examples of changing constants.php.